# Append 1 for the first occurence of an item in list p that occurs in list s, and append 0 for the other occurence and other items in s

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, loops

I want this code to append 1 for the first occurence of an item in list p that occurs in list s, and append 0 for the other occurence and other items in s.

That's my current code below and it is appending 1 for all occurences, I want it to append 1 for the first occurence alone. Please, help

```
s = [20, 39, 0, 87, 13, 0, 23, 56, 12, 13]
p = [0, 13]
bin = []

for i in s:
        if i in p:        
            bin.append(1)      
        else:
            bin.append(0)
   

print(bin)

# current result [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
# excepted result [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution is to remove the item from list `p` if found:

```py
s = [20, 39, 0, 87, 13, 0, 23, 56, 12, 13]
p = [0, 13]

out = []
for i in s:
    if i in p:
        out.append(1)
        p.remove(i)
    else:
        out.append(0)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Nice one. But you have to remember that you modified `p` if you need it later and that might not be obvious if this code is in a function.

Answer (score 3):

Use `index` to find the first occurrence in a list.

```
s = [20, 39, 0, 87, 13, 0, 23, 56, 12, 13]
p = [0, 13]
bin = [0] * len(s)
for value in p:
    bin[s.index(value)] = 1
```

Comment: `index` becomes slow as the object in question grows

Answer (score 3):

You have to remember if you have seen the element once. Use a set for that.

```
s = [20, 39, 0, 87, 13, 0, 23, 56, 12, 13]
p = [0, 13]
bin = []
seen = set()

for i in s:
    if i in p:
        if i in seen:
            bin.append(0)
        else:
            bin.append(1)
            seen.add(i)
    else:
        bin.append(0)

print(bin)
```

The result is `[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

This runs over the data only once and doesn't modify any of the input values.

---

A compressed version of the loop:

```
for i in s:
    if i in p and i not in seen:
        bin.append(1)
        seen.add(i)
    else:
        bin.append(0)
```

Comment: "This runs over the data only once" - It runs over `p` multiple times.

Comment: I meant the _main_ data, not the lookup table. But if that is an issue one could convert `p` to a set.

Answer (score 3):

O(|s|+|p|) time and doesn't modify the inputs: ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxNDsIgEIX3nGKWkJCmhVTroidp3ChtnBhhAmx6enzo6v3MN0/O@krRL5JbK7TS5kZL/mYJslwtTf5nHWS@ILpe3ZV0dPx7FRACP@tw5PR572fRgosZJIl6cOxo0IwdQ0fKxISu4E8yx6pBmNa@)):

```
d = dict.fromkeys(p, 1).pop
bin = [d(i, 0) for i in s]
```

Answer (score 2):

As some correctly pointed out, some of the solutions change `s` and `p`, hence re-runs are inconsistent. So be careful with that.

I would wrap this using a nice method:

```
import copy

def mark_first_key_occurence(values, keys):

  def account_for(v, c):
    if v not in c:
      return 0

    c.remove(v)
    return 1

  keys_copy = copy.deepcopy(keys)
  return [account_for(v, keys_copy) for v in values]
```

Then call it using:

```
s = [20, 39, 0, 87, 13, 0, 23, 56, 12, 13]
p = [0, 13]

print(mark_first_key_occurence(s, p))
```

**UPDATE**: Kelly's solutions is without any doubt the best one. Lists don't have a `pop`-like method with a default, but using a dict is definitely a neat trick! **Please give him the credit.**
Here it is with my minor touch (I think calling `pop` explicitly is cleaner)

```
d = dict.fromkeys(p, 1)
print([d.pop(i, 0) for i in s])
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect `print([account_for(x, p) for x in s])` to give two different results if I call it in two subsequent lines.

Comment: Well you would obviously wrap that using a method and work on a copy of the original `p` value...

Answer (score 0):

```
s = [20, 39, 0, 87, 13, 0, 23, 56, 12, 13]
p = [0, 13]
bin = [0]*len(s) # let the array contain only 0

for i in p: # for each element in p
    flag = False # this flag is made to true if the first occurence has been set to 1 in the bin array
    for j in range(len(s)):
        if((s[j]==i) and (not flag)):
            bin[j] = 1
            flag = True
print(bin)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

More elegant way:

```
  s = [20, 39, 0, 87, 13, 0, 23, 56, 12, 13]
  p = [0, 13]
  bin = [1 if x in p else 0 for x in s]
  idxs = [idx for idx, item in enumerate(s) if item in s[:idx]]
  for idx in idxs:
      bin [idx] = 0
  print(bin)

[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```